# Show that if S is a finite spanning set of $n$ distinct vectors of a vector space V. Then V is finite dimensional and $\dim(V) \leq n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am grappling with the following problem

> Let S be a finite spanning set of $n$ vectors of a vector space V. Then V is finite dimensional and $\dim(V) \leq n$.

I have attempted to show that this holds and this is what I have now

> If $S = \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{Span}(S) = V = \{0\}$ so the result is clearly true when $S$ is empty. Suppose now that S is non-empty. We will show that there is a linearly independent subset of $S$ that spans V algorithmically. If $S$ is linearly independent we are done. Otherwise we can find a vector $s_1 \in S$ such that $\operatorname{Span}(S − \{s_1\}) = V$. If $S − \{s_1\}$ is linearly independent we are done. Otherwise again we may find a vector $s_2 \in S− \{s_1\}$ such that $\operatorname{Span}(S − \{s_1,s_2\}) = V$. We continue in this manner until we finally have a linearly independent subset of $S$.

I'm not sure how to conclude that my process will end or if it is even correct. I'm fairly new to proving so I will appreciate any help, suggestions and corrections.

My line of thought for my original solution was that if we already have S to be linearly independent then we don't need to show anything. If that wern't true then we can find a vector in $S$ such if we removed it the smaller set would still span V like S. Then we apply the procedure again on the smaller set stopping if the set is linearly independent. Otherwise we continue to rip out vectors resulting in a smaller set that still spans V. I assumed that since $S$ was finite that my process would end and if it does end then we have a finite basis for $V$.

EDIT 1: I thank @Matias Heikkilä and @mathcounterexamples.net for their suggestion to reformulate my proof as an induction proof. What I have managed to produce is the following

**Problem:** Let V be a vector space and $S = \{s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n\}$ where all the vectors in $S$ are distinct vectors in $V$ and $n \geq 1$ such that $\operatorname{Span}(S) = V$. Then S contains a finite basis of V.

We proceed by induction on n.

**Base step ($n=1$):** If $n = 1$, then $S = \{s_1\}$. If $S$ is linearly independent then $S$ forms a finite basis of V. If on the other hand $S$ is linearly dependent then $S - \{s_1\} = \emptyset$ spans $S$ which is finite and linearly independent subset that spans $V = \{0\}$. In either case we have a finite subset of $S$ that forms a basis of V. Thus our proposition holds for the base case.

**Inductive step**: Suppose inductively for a fixed $n > 1$ that we have have proved the result for $n -1$. We wish to show that the result holds for $n$. That is the set $S =  \{s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n\}$ contains a subset $B$ that forms a basis of V. Suppose that $S$ were linearly independent then we set $B = S$ and we are done. If on the other hand $S$ were linearly dependent then we can find a vector $v_1 \in S$ such that $\operatorname{Span}(S - \{v_1\}) = \operatorname{Span}(S) = V$. We note that $S - \{v_1\}$ is a set of $n-1$ elements which span $V$ thus we may let $S'= S - \{v_1\} $ and apply our induction hypothesis to $S'$. Whence there is a finite subset $B$ of $S'$ which forms a basis of $V$. But $B$ is also a finite subset of $S'$. Thus $S$ contains a finite subset that forms a basis of $V$. This completes the inductive step.

**Conclusion:** By the principle of mathematical induction, the proposition is true for all $n \geq 1$ $\Box$

Im still unsure of the validity of my original proof and the inductive proof above.

Comment: The point is that $S$ contains a basis of $\text{span}(S)$ and you seem to have understood that. I'm pretty sure the argument could be made much simpler though. EDIT: Took a look around a bit, but couldn't find a pretty one-liner that would give the result :(

Comment: What you did is to use induction in disguise. Why not using a proper induction proof on $n$?

Comment: @Matias Im having trouble with figuring out whether the process at the end of my current solution is correct. Are there any glaring problems?

Comment: I think the main problem is it's "not pretty", meaning that the crux of the matter is hard to see and hence it's hard to say if it's actually correct or if you missed some essential detail. Maybe it would indeed help if you formulated this as a proper induction proof.

Comment: I see. I'll try formulate an induction proof and edit it into my question.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have tried to reformulate my proof as an induction proof. Im not sure if I got it down correctly.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä